# What is the interface between LaTeX and BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Precisely what is the "protocol" between LaTeX and BibTeX?

That is, if I run `latex foo`, `bibtex foo`, and `latex foo`, exactly how does information flow from LaTeX to BibTeX and back?

---

My current *guess* is that the data flows are as follows:

1. LaTeX generates the file `foo.aux`.
2. BibTeX reads the file `foo.aux`. It only pays attention to lines of the form `\citation{...}`, `\bibstyle{...}`, and `\bibdata{...}`.
3. BibTeX generates the file `foo.bbl`.
4. When LaTeX notices that `foo.bbl` exists, the `\bibliography` command behaves like `\input{foo.bbl}`.

Is this accurate or is there more to it? For example, is `\citation{...}` always precisely one line of text?

Are there some commonly used document classes and packages that affect the protocol somehow? Obviously with `biblatex` things will be different, but is there anything less obvious to be aware of?

---

Background: I am interested in writing a script that I could use as a drop-in replacement for BibTeX (in the sense that from the LaTeX side, nothing would change, but the generation of the `foo.bbl` file would be different).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your guess is more-or-less correct, including the fact that `biblatex` alters the approach a bit (other packages modify it also, but not to the same degree). Taking the simplest case of a single `.tex` file without any requirement for multiple bibliographies or similar:

- `\bibliographystyle` writes the `\bibstyle{...}` line to the `.aux` file: this can therefore be given in the preamble
- `\bibliography` writes the `\bibdata{...}` line to the `.aux` file, and also inputs the `.bbl` file, if it is available.
- `\cite` writes a `\citation{...}` line to the `.aux` file, and also creates the citation in the LaTeX document
- `\nocite` writes a `\citations{...}` line to the `.aux` file, but does not do anything in the LaTeX document.

When BibTeX reads the `.aux` file, it looks for one `\bibstyle` line and one `\bibdata` line along with multiple `\citation` lines. It will then write a `.bbl` file, but what goes in there depends on the instructions in the `.bst` file. The usual convention is that the `.bbl` file will contain just the `bibliography` environment which holds formatted citations, although this is not always the case.

There are many additions which can be made to this workflow. For example, `biblatex` defines `\bibliography` to be used in the preamble, as it does *not* work with a `.bbl` file containing data for printing directly. Multiple bibliographies may be created by using more than one `.aux` file to create a set of `.bbl` files. I've also seen an implementation where an XML version of the bibliography is written as a LaTeX 'comment' within the `.bbl` file. These approaches still use the same underlying interface, in the sense that BibTeX is still looking for the same commands in the `.aux` file and writing a `.bbl` file.

---

Taking the example of `multibib`, at the LaTeX end it defines a set of commands for each new type of bibliography, for example

```
\newcites{sec}{Secondary Literature}
```

creates a new citation command

```
\citesec{...}
```

These new commands write to a separate `.aux` file from the main one, which means that BibTeX has to be run twice, once on the `\jobname.aux` file and once on the `sec.aux` file. This will generate *two* `.bbl` files, `\jobname.bbl` and `sec.bbl`, which are then read as normal by `\bibliography` and `\bibliographysec`, respectively. Thus the overall process is almost unchanged from the standard case, but there are simply more files involved.

Answer (score 8):

yes, for the default case with one aux file. But there can be 2 or more aux files, eg using `multibib` or `chapterbib`or ... With`multibib` you have to run the main aux file and the one which is defined by the user; it also has the extension .aux For `chapterbib` you have one aux file per chapter. both cases are easy to handle: `bibtex *.aux`. Same for package `bibunits`.