# Efficient Strategy to cite papers

Tags: bibliographies

My strategy to cite papers has been to type all the information in manually within the body of the .tex file.  For example:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{mg} {\sc M. Gockenbach},
{\em Understanding and Implementing the Finite Element Method}, SIAM,
Philadelphia (2006)

...

\end{thebibliography}
```

When I search for articles on things like google scholar, I notice that I have the option of importing into BibTeX format, but it looks nothing like what I would type in the body of the article.  For example:

```
@article{biot1941general,
  title={General theory of three-dimensional consolidation},
  author={Biot, M.A.},
  journal={Journal of applied physics},
  volume={12},
  number={2},
  pages={155--164},
  year={1941},
  publisher={AIP}
}
```

So, I suspect there's a faster way to use this code to my advantage.  Can I simply put it into my latex file in the bibliography section?  Can I put it into a separate file and load the bibliography from that file into my .tex file?  How can I do this?

Comment: Some related questions: First, to understand the various options, see [bibtex vs biber and natbib vs biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693).  For some more detail on how BibTeX and LaTeX interact see [What is the interface between LaTeX and BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67944/2693)

Comment: And another: [Biblatex for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/2693) (I'm not responsible for the title!)

Comment: And one more that gives a broader overview along with some links more related questions: [What TeX software to write technical papers with](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470/2693).

Answer (score 5):

A file  named `example.tex` using  BibTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@article{biot1941general,
  title={General theory of three-dimensional consolidation},
  author={Biot, M.A.},
  journal={Journal of applied physics},
  volume={12},
  number={2},
  pages={155--164},
  year={1941},
  publisher={AIP}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
There are a  theory of 3D consolidation 
\cite{biot1941general}  in our references.
\bibliography{example.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

The  bibliography must be a separate file as `example.bib` or included in the document preamble as showed in this example. The file  `example.tex` must be usually compiled in this order:

```
pdflatex example.tex
bibtex  example
pdflatex example.tex
pdflatex example.tex
```

The result (`example.pdf`) must be:

[image: MWE]

A great advantage of this method instead of insert `\bibitem`s manually is that you can change the style of all the references simply changing `plain` with another style as `vancouver` for example. Then the author is not  "M. A. Biot" but "Biot MA.", the journal is not in cursive, etc. There a lot more options (`abbrv`, `acm`, etc.)

Another big advantage is that you can manage your references easily with programs as `JabRef`.

Only when you are comfortable managing .bib files and compiling LaTeX with BibTeX, is time to learn about the `natbib` and `biblatex` package.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put the BibTeX formatted code directly into your LaTeX file. But you put it into a BibTeX-file with extension `.bib` and include it in a certain way into your LaTeX document. Actually, you can put hundreds of such "@article"s (and there are other types "@book", "@techreport", and also "@inbook", "@inproceedings") into one BibTeX-file. Following file `refs.bib` is an example:

```
@ARTICLE{Smith1980,
  author = {Peter Smith},
  title = {A new analytic approach},
  journal = {Artificial Intelligence},
  volume = {14},
  issue = {2},
  pages = {329--334},
  year = {1980}
}
@BOOK{AlwaysCitedRef1999,
  author = {M. Miller},
  title = {The Big Reference},
  publisher = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
  year = {1999}
}
```

Using biblatex (kind of replacement of bibtex), your document `myarticle.tex` will look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}  %default style
%\usepackage[style=draft]{biblatex}  %maybe useful? difficult in bibtex!
\addbibresource{refs.bib}   %\bibliography{refs} is deprecated
\begin{document}
Hello world! (\cite{Smith1980})
\nocite{AlwaysCitedRef1999}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You need to compile the document by a sequence of commands.

1. `pdflatex myarticle.tex` will generate `myarticle.aux` that contains the bibtex-keys of all references you `\cite`'d (or `\nocite`'d), e.g. Smith1960 and AlwaysCitedRef1999.
2. `bibtex myarticle.aux` will process your `refs.bib` and sort out all the needed references into `myarticle.bbl`.
3. `pdflatex myarticle.tex` includes the bibliography `myarticle.bbl` into your pdf-output.

If you compile your document for the first time you might need to repeat step 2 and 3 until all page numbers are correct (actually, LaTeX will tell you to do so). This is because the 'insertion' of new text (the bibliography and the citations) into the pdf-output will change the page numbering.

*Note*: Only the `\cite`'d and `\nocite`'d papers will appear in your bibliography of your PDF file, not your entire collection!

---

**My typical work flow using JabRef (and sometimes Zotero)**

(1) **Downloading/Naming/Saving of files.**
After searching the web and finding a paper that has some useful information for me, I download the *paper* **and also** the *biliographic data*. For the latter, some webpages provide a bibtex-file for download as you have discovered. Others do not. In general, the bibliograpic data can be still found on the webpage. Hence, I have used the Addon Zotero for Firefox just to extract this information from the webpage and save it to a bibtex-file.

- I create a bibtex-key `BIBTEXKEY` for this paper. This key should to be unique among all papers you have now and in future! So choose wisely! ;-) That depends on your subject. For example, how many authors does a typical paper have? 2 or 10? Here are two examples for patterns for the bibtex-keys,

  - `<AuthorsEtAl><YEAR>-<InitTitle>` where `<AuthorsEtAl>` stands for the first 2 or 3 author names and "etal" appended for more authors, and `<InitTitle>` for first 3 initials of title;
  - `<YEAR>-<AuthorsShort>-<InitTitle>` where `<AuthorsShort>` stands for the first 3 letters of *each* author name;
- I save the PDF-paper as `BIBTEXKEY.pdf` and the bibliograpic data as `BIBTEXKEY.bib` in a folder for my not-yet-read papers. (Extending the filename is also possible, e.g. appending the title of the paper `BIBTEXKEY_ShortendPaperTitleHere.pdf`.)

(2) **Integration into the BibTeX-file.**
I have *one* folder that contains all my read papers and a BibTeX-file `refs.bib` as a database about them. The BibTeX-file is managed by the [program `JabRef`](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/). For the integration of the paper `BIBTEXKEY.pdf`, I move `BIBTEXKEY.pdf` into that folder for my read papers and import the file `BIBTEXKEY.bib` into `refs.bib` by JabRef (BIBTEXKEY.bib can be deleted afterwards).

(3) **Writing an own article.**
If "doc" is the folder with all the (LaTeX) files for my own article then I create a soft link to `refs.bib` in it. (You can also copy `refs.bib` to "doc" with the disadvantage that updates of the original file are missing in the copy.) In any case, after finalizing the article, I make sure that I have a permanent copy of `refs.bib` in folder "doc" for preservation purpose. Compilation of the LaTeX document works as shown above. (Actually, I am using [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) as editor to generate LaTeX.)

In sum, I have one folder with read papers and one BibTeX-file, which is managed by JabRef and used in all my works. The identification of papers is handled by BibTeX-keys.

Comment: you can depend only on `Zotero` to automatically generate `citation keys`, I use `zotero`+`biblatex`+`biber`+`TexStudio` to do this job, if interested you may have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973). Let me know, if `JabRef` can be totally left out to get the job done.

Comment: @doctorate Thx. JabRef can automatically generate custom BibTeX keys, too. I guess you can leave out JabRef. But for me, JabRef is easier to use and I hardly use Zotero: * In JabRef tags can be organized in a tree-like structure; * JabRef uses .bib file as its database (no need for import / export of .bib file); all PDF and PS files can be stored in one folder and JabRef can link entries of the ".bib" file *automatically* to them. (I like this simple structure with little overhead.) * JabRef has always been a standalone application, but nowadays Zotero can be used standalone, too.